# How do i round this values (IPython.display)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

Thank you for your attention.

I want to show dataframe inline and i found display_html

and i want to show this float value with round

this is my code

```
a = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]]
b = [[5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],[5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

space = "\xa0" * 10
display_html(df.head().style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")._repr_html_()
             + space +df2.head().style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")._repr_html_(), raw=True)
```

How can i make this values round up to 1.00 2.00

this is the output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS9Vp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style.set_precision()` to achieve the desired results:

```
a = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]]
b = [[5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],[5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

space = "\xa0" * 10
display_html(df.head().style.set_precision(2).set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")._repr_html_()
             + space +df2.head().style.set_precision(2).set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")._repr_html_(), raw=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did that it's worked.

But how could you found this answer?

i want to know to my improvement

Comment: In this case I had a similar piece of code in my repository but in general the best place to start looking is the API documentation, for example for pandas module: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html